# Parallel std::foreach loop calling a non-static class member function

Tags: c++, c++17

I would like to use C++17 parallel `std::foreach` to iterate over an operation involving a non-static class member function. Basically, each object of the class has its own version of the data and a method acting on that data, and I would like to run the method in parallel over a sequence of values (which are inputs to the method), updating the internal data. Something like following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>

class XYZ{
        std::vector<double> xvec_;
        double m;
  
    public:

        XYZ(std::vector<double> xvec) :xvec_{xvec}, m{0} {}
        
        
        void add_to_m(double x) {
            m += x;            
        }

        void add_up(){
            std::for_each(
                std::execution::par, 
                std::begin(xvec_), 
                std::end(xvec_), 
                add_to_m);           
        }

        void print_m() {
             std::cout << m << std::endl;
        }
};


int main(){
    XYZ xyz1({1,2,3.5,7.8});
    xyz1.add_up();
    xyz1.print_m();
    
    XYZ xyz2({1,2,8});
    xyz2.add_up();
    xyz2.print_m();
}
```

But this produces the following error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void XYZ::add_to_m(double)’
```

suggesting that the function passed to `std::for_each` has to be a static member. Making the function static is not an option since I would like each object to operate on its own version of the data. How can I implement this idea?

EDIT: If you want to get a working non-parallel version of the code, replace the `add_to_m` implementation above with

```cpp
void add_up(){   
  for (auto &x : xvec_) add_to_m(x);
}
```

Comment: _I would like each object to operate on its own version of the data_ But you only have one instance of `XYZ`...

Comment: @PaulSanders, not sure if I understand your comment. If you meant the example code, I have updated the example.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an object to `std::foreach` that contains some reference to `this` `XYZ`. Otherwise, how will it know on which object to call that method? A lambda will do

```
std::foreach(std::execution::par, std::begin(xvec_), std::end(xvec_), [&](double x) { add_to_m(x); });
```

Alternatively, `std::bind_front` works if you don't want to repeat the signature

```
std::foreach(std::execution::par, std::begin(xvec_), std::end(xvec_), std::bind_front(&XYZ::add_to_m, this));
```

`std::bind_front` produces a functor object just like a lambda, so that `std::bind_front(f, args...)(args2...)` performs `std::invoke(f, args..., args2...)`. Also, `std::invoke(f, recv, args...)` on a non-static member function pointer `f` and a pointer to an object which can receive that method `recv` acts as `recv->*f(args...)`.

`add_to_m`/`this->add_to_m`, on its own, is not a first-class "thing" that you can use as such an object. This is just C++'s design.

Do note that your current `add_to_m` would cause a race if actually run in parallel.

Comment: thanks. I did try the lambda approach, but was not sure what to capture. I am assuming that your version captures a lot (?). Can we just capture only `this` somehow? I don't want to capture anything unnecessary.

Comment: @passerby51 No, it only captures the `this` pointer. Replace `&` with `this` if it makes you feel better, but they mean the same thing here.

Comment: OK, great. The second approach looks interesting but I am not going to pretend I understand. Would you care adding a bit about what `std::bind_front` does and what *first-class "thing"* mean?

Comment: Isn't there a race condition on `XYZ::m`?

Comment: @PaulSanders Oop, yes. Presumably OP's actual method has the necessary protections.

Comment: @PaulSanders, yes, most likely. That is where I wanted to try out a `mutex` lock, but failed before getting there :)

Comment: @passerby51 "First-class" refers to language design; a language construct is first-class if it can be treated as "just another object". In C++, lambdas are first-class; they produce objects that you can pass around like any other. But member functions are not. They just don't "exist" as objects that you can copy around in C++.